# Upgrading RAM on A7V600

Tags: memory

The motherboard (Asus A7v600) has 3 DIMM slots and supports up to 3 GB of memory. It has limitation of maximum 2 DIMS on PC3200.

I am wondering what is the best memory configuration to run it on:

1. 3x1GB PC3200 - it says it supports maximum 2 PC3200, so what will happen in this case of adding 3?
2. 2x1GB PC3200 and 1x1GB PC2700 - I would assume this is the best performance, but is it? Which one is faster?
3. 3x1GB PC2700
4. Currently it has 2x512, so maybe adding 1x2gb pc3200 would be best?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no good configuration on this board: It's nearly 20 years old and runs DDR1-RAM. That said, you can use PC3200 and it will fall back as needed.

Comment: “so what will happen in this case of adding 3?” - **It won’t boot** Specifically, it won’t boot, if you attempt to boot with 3 PC3200 modules

Answer (score 1):

This is the computer that you are asking about in your other question.

Put in the 3 GB (as less is hopeless for Windows 10).

It will not matter what specific memory you use because it will all be slow.